# FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE getting lost when starting my foreground service

Tags: java, android, foreground-service, android-api-34

I have an app that requires capturing location information in a foreground service. It has been working until I raised my SDK versions to API 34 based on other needs.  I understand there are new requirements for foreground services in API 34 and have done my best to follow the recommended changes.  From testing, the parameters getting passed in ForegroundLocationService.class statement

```
     ServiceCompat.startForeground(this, 100, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
```

is lost when it goes through SystemForegroundService.class and causes the error as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection, PID: 18488
                                                                                                    android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS with type none callerApp=ProcessRecord{ed24bae 18488:com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection/u0a190} targetSDK=34 has been prohibited
                                                                                                        at android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException.java:53)
                                                                                                        at android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException.java:49)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4870)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:4852)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3052)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
                                                                                                        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6761)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:862)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService$Api29Impl.startForeground(SystemForegroundService.java:173)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService$1.run(SystemForegroundService.java:127)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

The following is my manifest items for permissions and the services

```
<service
            android:name="ForegroundLocationService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

        </service>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

The following is my ForegroundLocationService.class

```
package com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bugfender.sdk.Bugfender;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.function.Consumer;


public class ForegroundLocationService  extends Service {


    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
    public PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    public Context context;
    public BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    public IntentFilter intentFilter;
    @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        //Log.i(TAG, "LocationWorkManager ForegroundLocationService appLifecycleEvent onCreate: ");
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "LocationWorkManager " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ForegroundLocationService appLifecycleEvent onStartCommand: ");
            context = getApplicationContext();
            String input = "PeepsConnection is capturing current location if you have an open check in";
            createNotificationChannel();
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);

            // this is to verify permissions take out after testing
            boolean permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECSTED_DEVICE= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: FOREGROUND_SERVICE= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            permissionGrantedStatus = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!permissionGrantedStatus) {
                Bugfender.e(TAG, "ForegroundLocationService onStartCommand: FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION= " + permissionGrantedStatus);
            }
            // through here

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                                            Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                                                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)))))) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
                } else {
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
                }

                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle("Location Service Running")
                        .setContentText(input)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.map_marker_down)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .build();
                ServiceCompat.startForeground(this, 100, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
            }
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

        }
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        private void createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Foreground Service Channel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            }
        }
    }
```

When the app runs the method startForeground() in SystemForegroundService.class, this code is passed the parameters (1,0,Notification).  I have not been able to track it backwards to see where it is lost.

```
public void startForeground(
            final int notificationId,
            final int notificationType,
            @NonNull final Notification notification) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    Api29Impl.startForeground(SystemForegroundService.this, notificationId,
                            notification, notificationType);
                } else {
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification);
                }
            }
```

Attached is my build.gradle in case it a version issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection"
        minSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 2
        versionName "Beta 2.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    namespace 'com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'

    def work_version = "2.5.0"

    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"

    // optional - Multiprocess support

    implementation 'com.bugfender.sdk:android:3.+'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:$work_version"
    implementation group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1" // last SupportLib version
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'

    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.6.1"

    implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.4.0'
    //implementation "net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.3"
    implementation 'net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.5@aar'
    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

    // UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"

    // Testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'
}
```